# ¿Cómo leer el valor de una variable fuera de la función en la que ha sido declarada (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, variables

En una página web tengo dos archivos HTML. Uno de ellos es un formulario para poder enviar tu nombre al pulsar el botón de enviar. Almacena el nombre que le has puesto en una variable.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Introduce tu nombre</h1>
  <input type="text" id="name" required>
  <br>
  <button type="button" onclick="send()">Enviar</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Y luego tengo el archivo main.js

```js
function send() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
}
```

Bien, ¿cómo puedo hacer que en el archivo **index.html** (el otro archivo html) pueda leer esa variable y hacer algo así:

```
...
<h1 id="myName"><h1>
...

document.getElementById("myName").innerText = "Bienvenido"+name+", que tal";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si son htmls independientes, una opción puede ser guardando esa variable en `localStorage` o en `sessionStorage` depende de tus necesidades.

Para guardarla:

```
localStorage.setItem("name",value);
```

Y para recuperarla:

```
localStorage.getItem("name");
```

Ten en cuenta que lo que hay en `localStorage`, se quedará guardado hasta que tu lo elimines por código o el usuario limpie la cache y los datos de la web.

Si lo guardas en `sessionStorage` solo se mantendrá hasta que el usuario cierre la pestaña del navegador.

Comment: Vale, muchísimas gracias